# Displaying a WPF window when the project is a dll, not an exe

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

How do I display a wpf window in my application when the application resides in a dll, not an exe? This project will be compiled to a dll and loaded into another application as an add-in.

In WinForms, I would just have the following code:

```
dim frmUserData as frmDataEntry = new frmDataEntry
frmUserData.ShowDialog()
```

How do I accomplish the same task in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WPF you can just create the new window and show it.  It would look very similar to Winforms.

```
Dim wpfWindow as new WpfWindow()
wpfWindow.Show() 'or ShowDialog depending.
```

If the UI you're trying to show is a Page, and not a Window, then you'll need to create a NavigationWindow and use Navigate(), passing in the Page you want to use.

Comment: And for vb.net, just use Dim instead of var and remove the semicolons.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Dennis, I've changed my answer to VB

Comment: This was a case of user error. I thought it was the same. It turns out I was looking for frmDataEntry when I should have been looking for MainWindow. . . Thanks for help!